# Observable collection with current item?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

In a dialog from my application, I have an observable collection (stored somewhere else) bound to a list of tabs. When I close and reopen the dialog, the currently selected tab gets lost and winds up to the be the first one. How do I set up my tabs so that the selected tab persists?

I had the impression that the observable collection had "current item" property, but that doesn't seem to be case. I've looked at ItemCollection and CollectionView, which do have a current item property, but I'm not sure if that's that I'd be interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Closing` event of your dialog, save away the currently selected `TabItem`.

In the `Loaded` event of your dialog, simply say:

```
yourTabControl.SelectedItem = _savedTab;
```

Code-behind is the easiest way to accomplish this. `ObservableCollection` is not going to help you.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but I will answer for those might be looking for this...

The way I handled this using the MVVM pattern was to have on my ViewModel both an ObservableCollection to which the TabControl binds its ItemsSource as well as an ActiveItem property to which the TabControl binds its SelectedItem property.

It works pretty well and keeps the design principles of MVVM (ie, the ViewModel should not be aware of the view).